# How to display uploaded file in jquery pop up window?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently i am displaying file in new window. It is working fine. I want to display file in jquery pop up. This is the code i have.

```
 public ActionResult Download(string filepath)
        {
            service.Service objService = new service.Service();
            byte[] result = objService.DownloadFileFromDMS(filepath);
            string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);

            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath),
                Inline = true,
            };
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            return File(result, contentType);

        }
```

Here byte[] recieves bytes from the server. Instead of displaying it in new window, I want to display in jquery pop up. Can anybody suggest me how to do this?

Comment: When you say display a file, do you want to make a preview for the file? r just a download link?

Comment: Preview of the file in modal pop up. Here i am receiving file from server.

Comment: Then you need to get a plugin to do that, possibly with Flash, there are no native components in a web browser to display documents like that. Images are easy but documents such as PDF docs or Word docs become more complicated. Perhaps have a look at how google drive does its implementation of the preview, and perhaps you can integrate to that platform.

Comment: can i download file to one folder inside the project and by using file name can i preview file?

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/01/11/Preview-Word-files-(docx)-in-HTML-using-ASPNET-OpenXML-and-LINQ-to-XML.aspx or just google "Preview Documents online using asp.net-mvc 4

Comment: Is it possible to download file to folder inside the project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107700/discussion-between-jacques-koekemoer-and-niranjan).